# From Open Sets to Lower Semi-Continuous Functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Assume that a nonnegative function $g$ is such that
\begin{align*}
g(x)\geq\chi_{U}(x)~\text{a.e. implies } g(x)\geq\chi_{U}(x)~\text{everywhere},
\end{align*}
where $\chi_{U}$ is the characteristic function of an open set $U$, and the underlying measure is the usual Lebesgue in Euclidean space.

Does it follow that
\begin{align*}
g(x)\geq\varphi(x)~\text{a.e. implies } g(x)\geq\varphi(x)~\text{everywhere},
\end{align*}
for a nonnegative lower semi-continuous function $\varphi$?

There is a trick in the book of Gerald B. Folland that, for such a function $\varphi$, we can find an increasing sequence $\{\varphi_{n}\}$ of simple functions such that $\varphi_{n}(x)\uparrow\varphi(x)$ everywhere and
\begin{align*}
\varphi_{n}(x)=\dfrac{1}{2^{n}}\sum_{j=1}^{2^{2n}}\chi_{U_{n,j}}(x),~~~~U_{n,j}=\{x:\varphi(x)>j2^{-n}\},~~~~j=1,...,2^{2n}.
\end{align*}
But then what can we do?